# Code syntax error edit often rejected

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, too-minor

For a few times, I have seen code in an answer has syntax error, but when I try to correct those, the edit gets rejected for several reasons.

One example is https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1937652, where the provided code does not run at all due to syntax error. The rejected reasons are:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

I think whether the code can run or not is pretty substantial. I tried to improve the formatting a bit too so it fits the "multiple issues" requirement.

Is it possible to change the edit review rule so this can pass, or change the review process in general? Or we can only leave a comment to the answerer (who sometimes won't respond at all)

Comment: It was really a **minor edit**.

Comment: But the code does not work without that edit. Each future visitor all have to spot that syntax error and correct it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edits should not change the inherent meaning of an answer, even if that post is wrong. Wrong answers serve as a reference for other users. However, I think minor typos are independent of the meaning of an answer.

That being said, I personally think this is an acceptable edit. There's not much else to clean up in this answer. If that truly is just a stupid typo, then I think it's okay to edit, but ***make sure you know it's a typo first***.

Note: this only applies to *answers*. Do not edit *questions* for code proofreading, as those typos may actually be in their code. Generally, try to message the poster first, and ask them to change it.

Comment: Even in answers, be triple sure that the answer isn't including a code snippet with an error in order to make its point.